# How to hide a custom class label in a table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I have a table view controller with a custom cell and a CustomCell class. The code in the VC looks like this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Actual", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell

    let mySeries = series[indexPath.row] as Series
    cell.mySeries = mySeries
    return cell
}
```

The CustomClass code is the following:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var seasonLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var episodeLabel: UILabel!

var mySeries: Series! {
    didSet {
        nameLabel.text = mySeries.name
        seasonLabel.text = mySeries.season
        episodeLabel.text = mySeries.episode
    }
}
```

Everything works fine so far. But I made the cells editable and the reordering symbol (three stripes) is now laying over my episodeLabel. So I'd like to hide this label until the editing is done. The editing function for reordering looks like this:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to toIndexPath:IndexPath) {

    let customCell = CustomCell()
    customCell.episodeLabel.isHidden = true

    let rowToMove = series[fromIndexPath.row]
    series.remove(at: fromIndexPath.row)
    series.insert(rowToMove, at: toIndexPath.row)
}
```

This is the part which is working. But when I create an instance of the CustomCell class (customCell) and insert this line in the function above I get an fatal error because nil is found:

```
customCell.episodeLabel.isHidden = true
```

Same behavior when I create a function hideEpisodeLabel() in the CustomCell class and call it from the VC. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you shared more of the code around isHidden = true. What are you doing to get access to that customCell?

Comment: Have you set a trailing constraint for the episodeLabel and thencell content view?  The reordering control should then shrink your label

Comment: How are you getting the custom cell index in `moveRowAt`?

Comment: `customCell.episodeLabel.isHidden = true` in which func is this line executed?

Comment: No, I don't use trailing constraints.

Comment: As I wrote, I created an instance of CustomCell and inserted these lines in the MoveRowAt method: let seriesCell = SeriesCell()
        seriesCell.episodeLabel.isHidden = true

Comment: No, I don't get the custom cell index yet. See my comment below the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This additional method hides the label in the desired way:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let customCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell
    customCell?.episodeLabel.isHidden = true
    return true
}
```

To bring the label back I have to reload the table view. This can be done by overriding the setEditing method:

```
    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if(!editing) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Now, in the 'cellForRowAt indexPath:' method I only have to set the label to: isHidden = false.

Answer (score 0):

you must get cell instance in `moveRowAt` func

```
let customCell= tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? SeriesCell
    customCell.episodeLabel.isHidden = true
 }
```

Comment: Probably my mistake is, that I don't get the customCell index yet. So your approach seems to be the right one. But when I insert your code, I get the error message: Use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'. Maybe it is not Swift 3 compliant?

Comment: Swift 3: let customCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell -> same error

Comment: OMG, it's "fromIndexPath" or "toIndexPath" in your code. @Martin

Comment: Solved it, see below